# Which of these are essential for vacation: tripod, flash, extra batteries and memory cards, prime lens?

Tags: lens, tripod, travel, roadtrip

I have the Nikon D3200 with the kit lens (18mm - 55mm).

I'm going on a road trip soon and I'd like to take pictures of Christmas lights, Christmas trees, architecture, detail shots and photos inside museums.

I've been thinking of adding some equipment before the trip, but I'm not sure what's a must-have and what is just nice-to-have.

Here is what I'm considering:

- Tripod (Dolica TX570DS Ultra Compact Tripod with Professional Ball Head and Built-In Monopod)
- Flash (Altura Photo AP-UNV1 Speedlite Flash Kit)
- An extra battery
- An extra memory card
- Prime lens (Nikon AF-S DX NIKKOR 35mm f/1.8G)

I'm tempted to get the prime lens, because I've heard so many good things about it, and it would help me to take better low light photos. I've been using my zoom lens set to 35mm to get the hang of it and it's actually the position that I prefer. But it's the most expensive thing on this list and I already have a lens.

I don't currently have a tripod, flash, or remote control. These could come in handy not only on vacation but when I'm taking pictures at home in the evening, when there is no longer any natural light.

What would you recommend?

Comment: Depending on how long the trip lasts, I would take not 1 but 2-3 extra memory cards.

Comment: The trip is 10 days. I'm planning to download the photos to dropbox each night.

Comment: I would suggest retitling this to focus on your actual subjects and goals; the answer to the current title question is "none of them are essential; you could leave them at home and enjoy the moment without recording it". But this is really  _photography road trip_, and answers generally applicable to just _any_ vacation aren't necessarily right.

Comment: You said you don't have tripod, flash, or remote.  If you don't use them now, you are even less likely to use them on a vacation.   I find one 32GB card works for a 12 day vacation (with 30MB raw images), but a spare card would be very wise. A battery charger would be very wise.

Comment: You don't say if you have any companions traveling with you. That would be my determining factor. My wife and son will tolerate lens switching and quick on-camera flash use, but almost never a tripod.

Comment: My husband is going with me. He will only stand around and let me take photos for so long (not that I blame him), so a tripod might be going overboard. In that case, if I don't have a lot of light and the tripod is a no-go, maybe the flash or lens would be better? I also doubt that I'd want to lug around a tripod while we sightsee.

Comment: A monopod and a beanbag are better in this case than a tripod as they are less of a trip hazard for you and those around you.  That flash is going to be a heap of garbage.  An extra battery is handy in the cold as you can keep one warm in a pocket - cheap ones can be a false economy though.  Extra memory cards are cheap, buy loads.  The kit lens on the 3200 doesn't exactly set the world on fire but works for you.  A remote is extra stuff to carry when you really only need the self-timer.  All those are entirely my opinion, which is why I voted to close this q. as primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**4) Lens**
Given your wide subject range, you are probably ok with the lens. You likely will use the wide end more, and have little use for tele beyond what you have.

**3) Memory card**
If you shoot RAW, extra memory cards are a must no matter what the occasion. If you shoot only JPEG, then it is not as big a concern, as you can get many more images per card.

**2) Battery**
If you have access to power, then you should be good with a single battery if you charge every evening/over night. However, if you have VR lens or if your camera has built in GPS, you will need an additional battery

**1) Tripod**
In my opinion, for your intended case, Christmas lights, trees, architecture, my assumption is that these images will not be in bright daylight, but instead evening shots. In this case, the most useful item is going to be a tripod above everything else. Your shots will be done with low shutter speeds, especially if you wish to have the ISOs at manageable levels (below 800). This will demand a very steady camera, far more steady that you can get hand-held, even with VR.

Comment: I've decided to go with 1-3 and save the lens for another time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just my 2¢, but without a charged battery, all the other stuff becomes useless, so I'd say **your #1 priority is to get a car charger for your camera batteries**.

Extra batteries and memory cards are useful, but if you can download *and backup* the images (never feel secure with only one copy of your images), and clear off the cards every day, you may or may not need a lot of extras, depending on how much you shoot and the individual capacity of the cards.

If you're planning mostly on doing Christmas light shooting and architecture, the tripod is probably the piece you'll want the most, and the fast lens the one you want the least.

If you're planning on mostly doing museum shots, then the fast lens is the one you want the most and the tripod the one you want the least.

The flash... just me, but a $35 manual-only flash is not a great investment as your first/only flash. I'd *highly* recommend budgeting upwards and saving something closer to US$150-$200 for your first flash, and getting something with TTL capability and a good reputation.  Flash can be more transformative to your photography than a new lens, you should budget accordingly.

See also: [What features should one look for when selecting a flash?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17722/what-features-should-one-look-for-when-selecting-a-flash)

Answer (score 1):

This is totally opinion based. But my priority list would be.

**1)** 1-3 extra memory cards. Depending on the duration of the trip. So you do not need to download the cards to a laptop.

**2)** You probably can not use a tripod on a museum, but probably you can use a monopod. There are some with a tiny tripod on the far end. https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=monopod+with+legs

**3)** One interesting thing you can use on a urban architecture trip is a neutral density filter.

In conjunction with a real tripod (not a monopod), you can use a very low speed to blur the people passing by and take interesting images on outdoor landscapes.

From there you can go several ways.

- You will need a flash mainly if you are taking photos of people. But you can not use it on museums. If your priority are not people, but landscapes (including urban landscapes), you do not really need it.
- The prime lens could be an interesting option but only if you are NOT satisfied with the quality of your current lens, or you feel some clear disadvantages now. Probably the focal length, the speed or the sharpness. If you do not notice the diference, probably it is too soon.
- I would consider an extra batery or 2 but if i was on a wildlife trip. On a city, where you will be in an hotel at night it is probably not a real issue. Mainly if you are not using the flash to focus, iluminating a scene or using too much the live view.
- You do not need a remote control, again, except if you have already being in a situation where you need it. If you are in a lonley place, like a mountain and you want a selfie, yes. If you want to be in a family picture, yes. For a trip, I do not think so.

Comment: The disadvantage that I find with my current lens is that I can't open the aperture very wide, and I end up compensating with shutter speed or ISO. ISO can get grainy and sometimes I want to use a faster shutter speed but can't.

Comment: My first choice would be the tripod, before a wide aperture lens, becouse you first need to define what focal leingth you like the most.

Answer (score 1):

Two of the items in your list are, in my opinion, not optional.

- Extra battery: you need a second battery. *Need.* For me, especially while on vacation, it's easy to use up a whole battery's charge, forget to stick it in the charger at the end of a long day, etc. See also: [What do camera experts do for cameras that take too much battery power?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22978/what-do-camera-experts-do-for-cameras-that-take-too-much-battery-power/22980#22980)
- Extra memory card: well, first, evaluate how many photos will fit on the card you have, in your preferred format. If you can fit thousands, you probably don't *need* another memory card. 200-300? You need another memory card. Again, for me, especially while on vacation, it's easy to fill a memory card, or forget to transfer photos to the computer at the end of the day, etc. Also, if you're not taking a computer (or other device you can transfer photos to), then that should mean you get *at least* one, maybe two, more cards.

Answer (score 1):

Take some 'test' shots around your home before you go. Get familiar with the camera. You don't want to learn how to use a function when the 'once in a lifetime' photo happens in front of you! Take some photos of lights at night. Take pictures with street-lights, etc.
And, as many mentioned before, extra batteries, extra memory cards.